# Android - Change Image View On Click

Tags: android, imageview

I have a set of image view that I want to change when it is clicked. The first view is set by default, and I want the second one to appear when the first one is clicked. I also want the reverse to occur when the second one is visible. How can I do this? (Example: Default is Img 1 default, img 2 hidden. On click, img 2 shows, img 1 is hidden. On click again, reverse occurs).

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm_off_75dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="134dp" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm_on_75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="134dp" />
```

Comment: Added the code. It is only XML. I know there is a way to do this with Java, but I do not know how and cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the Following Code:**

```
ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
ImageView img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);

        img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                img1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

in both of button onclick you must check to see if other button is not visible then set it visible and if it is visible then do not do any thing. you can check visibility of buttons with this code
`if(mybutton.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
{
//set visibiliy of mybutton
}`